# C# int type in foreach Statement

Tags: c#, foreach

But I have a code in C# that does not work.

```
foreach(int CharLength in Char.Length)
{
 //Code Here

}
```

However I get an error that say that I cannot pass an int type in the foreach statement.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve?, `foreach` will work only in a collection

Comment: `foreach` is for iterating over a collection. Common pattern would indicate that `Char.Length` would be an integer value, not a collection. Are you sure you are attempting to iterate over the correct thing?

Comment: Yeah... that code makes no sense at all.

Comment: `for (int CharLengh = 0; CharLength < Char.Length; CharLength++) {}`

Comment: Write down a`for` loop that you are trying to convert to a `foreach` so we understand more of what you want to acheive

Comment: To the people voting for close, why exacly?  As far as I know there is no rule that exclude questions for being too trivial.

Comment: @Newtopian But there *is* a close reason for not providing a complete code snippet to replicate a described problem.  You can see as much yourself by simply checking what close reasons people voted for, rather than commenting to ask a question easily accessible to you.

Comment: @Servy I think in this case the code snippet is quite sufficient to understand what the problem is.  The votes are cast as "off topic", I was curious to know how a question about programming (however trivial for experienced programmers) can be off-topic here.  Votes to close marked as Unclear would have been perhaps more appropriate, but off-topic is beyond me.

Comment: @Newtopian The close votes were for, "Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

Answer (score 11):

What you're probably looking for is

```
// Enumerable.Range gives you 1,2,3,...Char.Length
foreach(int CharLength in Enumerable.Range(1, Char.Length))
```

or

```
// this sets CharLength to 0, 1, 2, ... CharLength-1
for(int CharLength = 0; CharLength < Char.Length; CharLength++)
```

Comment: Dude a big thanks, like I cannot stress enough how helpful that was, It was EXACTLY what i was looking for. Sorry if it was an annoying question, I'm still new to C# I just moved from Mastering Python and i though the syntax was the same.

Comment: No problem. I think Enumerable.Range is basically copied from Python anyway

Answer (score 1):

`System.Int` does not implement `IEnumerable` interface that is the reason you can not pass int in `foreach` loop. Any class which implements `IEnumerable` can be iterated using `foreach`. In your case `Char.Length` is an integer and cannot be iterated hence compiler throws error. Hope its clear.

Answer (score 0):

The foreach and for loops are different and operates differently.

The [for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) loop has three distinct operations in it's parenthesis, each of which are optionnal.

for(;;) will therefore generate an infinite loop the same as while(true) would.

The first part is done before the loops starts and typically is used to initialize an index variable.  It is executed only once before the first run.

The second is a test to determine if the loop should stop or continue.  It is executed just before starting the loop's body every time around the loop, including the very first time.

The third is an operation that is done each time the loop ends after the test operation is computed.

The [foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) works differently, there is only a single statement.  It defines a variable thas is scoped (just like the first part of the for loop above) to the loop body.  This variable is paired with a Collection that contains elements of the same type as that variable. Then each time the loop starts the variable is assigned to the next element in this collection.  The loop ends when the loop has gone through all the elements in the collection.

This process is known as enumerating the elements of a collection.  For a class to be enumerable (considered as a collection in this explanation) it must implement the [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

In your loop, the reason it does not work is that you declare a variable of type int and try to enumerate the collection returned by Char.length which is itself int but not an IEnumerable.

I hope this helps explain why the compiler seemed to complain som much about it.